# How to load partial view in Bootstrap Modal Popup and pass parameter to actionresult to load grid on modal window load?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

There is a problem to load partial view in Bootstrap Modal popup. Can I pass prodId as parameter to modal popup as well?

**Controller Action :**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Details(string INFO)
{
    return PartialView("DetailsPartialView");
}
```

**Model :**

```
<div class="modal" id="DetailsPopup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static"
  data-keyboard="true" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      @Html.Partial("../Controller/DetailsPartialView")
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Button:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnDetails">Details</button>

$("#btnDetails").click(function () {
    $('#DetailsPopup').appendTo("body").modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data into Html.Partial as such:

```
<div class="modal" id="DetailsPopup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="true" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            @Html.Partial("../Controller/DetailsPartialView", new { id = yourId })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you just use it in the partial view just like you do in a regular view. You can also pass a model class if you are more comfortable with that.